# Constructing matrix with nullspace containing particular vector

Tags: linear-algebra

How can we construct a matrix $A$ such that $Null(A)$ contains the vector $u=\begin{pmatrix}2\\1\\2\end{pmatrix}$?

Thanks :)

Comment: Are you familiar with the definition of $Null(A)$ (otherwise known as $ker(A)$)?

Comment: @andybenji I know what is $Ker$ but what is $Null$ I don't know. Thanks :)

Comment: Just let $A$ be the 3x3 zero matrix.  Then every vector is in $Null(A)$.  Did you mean to say find *all* matrices $A$ with this property?

Comment: The null space is the kernel. Try choosing a vector $x$ such that $x^T u = 0$. Pick $x_1=x_2 =1$ and then figure out what $x_3$ must be in order to satisfy the requirement. Then let $A = x^T$. (Logan's answer is even simpler.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: what can you say about the rows of such a matrix?

Answer (score 1):

If $A$ is a $3 \times 3$ matrix, then find any vector $v$ that is orthogonal to $u$, and let $A=vv^T$.

Comment: If A is 3x3 then ${\rm null}(A)$ is empty. A needs to be 2x3.

Comment: @ja72 how about $A=\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & -1 \\ 0 & 0& 0\\ -1 & 0 &1 \end{bmatrix}$

Comment: Ok I see your point.

Answer (score 1):

In MATLAB

```
v = [2;1;2];

A = null(v.')

A = |-1/2, -1|
    |   1,  0|
    |   0,  1|

null(A.')= | 1 |  % which is co linear with v
           |1/2|
           | 1 |
```

in general for the ${\rm null} \begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \\ z \end{pmatrix}^\top$ I calculate $\begin{pmatrix} -y & -x z \\ x & -y z \\ 0 & x^2+y^2 \end{pmatrix}$