# Similar matrices - find a matrix $T$

Tags: matrices

The matrices $A=\begin{pmatrix}5 & -3 \\ 4 & -2\end{pmatrix}$ and $B=\begin{pmatrix}-1 & 1\\-6 & 4\end{pmatrix}$ are similar. By knowing that similar matrices have the same eigenvalues, find a matrix $T$ such that $A=TBT^{-1}.$

any idea or proof is welcome :) thanks .

Comment: No, they are not similar.

Comment: They cannot be similar because neither their determinant nor their trace are equal...unless you're working on a field of characteristic $\,2\,$ ...

Comment: sorry, I fix the mistake

Comment: Oh, *now* that looks better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Evaluate $\,A'$s eigenvalues:

$$p_A(t):=\det(tI-A)=\left|\begin{array}{}t-5&\;\;\;3\\-4&t+2\end{array}\right|=t^2-3t+2=(t-2)(t-1)$$

Thus, the eigenvalues of $\,A\,$ are $\,1,2\,$. Find now one eigenvector for each eigenvalue:

$$(i)\;\;t=1:\;\;\;\;\;\;-4x+3y=0\Longleftrightarrow y=\frac{4}{3}x\Longrightarrow \binom{3}{4}$$
$${}$$

$$(i)\;\;t=2:\,\,\,\,\,\,-3x+3y=0\Longleftrightarrow x=y\Longrightarrow \binom{1}{1}$$

Well, as we know, we get that

$$S=\left(\begin{array}{}3&1\\4&1\end{array}\right)$$

Take it from here

Comment: But $A \neq TBT^{-1}$

Comment: I messed up both the letter and the rows and columns of the last matrix. Now, $$\,S^{-1}AS=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&2\end{pmatrix}=R^{-1}BR\,$$ ,and you can get the matrix $\,R\,$ for $\,B\,$ by the same method as we got $\,S\,$ for $\,A\,$ above, so now yes: *take it from here*

Comment: Could you give me more details, please. After I found matrix $S$ which is the next step? Finding  matrix $R$ and then what about $T$ ? thanks:)

Comment: Read my last, edited message, @Iuli

Comment: @DonAntonie Thanks :) it is interesting. Could you give some ideas about http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/247720/constructing-matrix-with-nullspace-containing-particular-vector. merci :)